# "Wide character in substition" messages from Lingua::EN::Sentence

Tags: perl, utf-8

I've used [`Lingua::EN::Sentence`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::EN::Sentence) for some time with no problem. Now suddenly it's started giving me "wide character in substitution" messages such as:

> Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373,  chunk 55.

Any idea why these have started appearing, and how I can get rid of them? The input file is set to `:utf8` and the output looks OK. I would just like it to stop spitting out warning messages.

Here is some of the code in the program:

```
local $/ = undef; 
binmode TXT, ":utf8"; 
my $txtdat = <TXT>;
my @paras = split("\n", $txtdat); 
foreach my $para (@paras) { 
    my $sentences = get_sentences($para);
}
```

Comment: Please show your code. We need to be able to reproduce this before we can help you properly

Comment: Are you using `use locale`?

Comment: `local $/ = undef;
 binmode TXT, ":utf8";
 my $txtdat = <TXT>;
 my @paras = split("\n", $txtdat);
 foreach my $para (@paras) {
  my $sentences = get_sentences($para);
 }`

Comment: Is this helpful? That's a code snippet calling get_sentences from the module. The input itself is actually confidential, but they're Unicode files, as you might imagine.

Comment: No, I'm not using `use locale`.

Comment: Your `local $/ = undef; `, `my $txtdat = <TXT>;` and `my @paras = split("\n", $txtdat);` can be replaced with the single line `my @paras = <TXT>;`. That won't solve your problem, but it does make your code simpler.

Comment: I'm guessing that the inputs need to be encoded according to your locale. (If so, the outputs will surely need decoding.)

Answer (score 3):

I think this must be a bug in [`Lingua::EN::Sentence`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::EN::Sentence)

Part of its initialisation sets the locale like this

```perl
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "fr_CA.ISO8859-1");
```

which is ISO-8859-1-encoded Canadian French. Nothing wrong with that, but it's a strange default

The module also exports a `set_locale` function, which calls [`POSIX::setlocale`](https://metacpan.org/pod/POSIX#FUNCTIONS) to set the locale to what you say, so in theory you could write

```perl
use Lingua::EN::Sentence qw/ get_sentences set_locale /;

set_locale('en_US.UTF-8');
```

and everything should work

But it doesn't, and I don't have time today to work out why it doesn't

I've been able to reproduce your problem with this

#### Perl code

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Data::Dump 'pp';

use Lingua::EN::Sentence qw/ get_sentences set_locale /;

set_locale('en_US.UTF-8');

my @paragraphs = do {
    open my $fh, '<:encoding(utf-8)', 'unicode.txt';
    <$fh>;
};

printf "Paragraphs: %s\n\n", pp \@paragraphs;

my $n;
for my $para ( @paragraphs ) {
    printf "Sentences in paragraph %d: %s\n\n",
            ++$n,
            pp get_sentences($para);
}
```

and this

#### input file

```
Here's a ‘quoted’ string. (The quotes are "wide" characters.) Another sentence in the same line. And another.

Here's another paragraph. With a second sentence.
```

(Why did I have to do that? You're in a much better position to recreate the problem with non-sensitive data.)

#### output

```
Wide character (U+2018) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 432.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 432.
Wide character (U+2018) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 433.
Wide character (U+2018) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 433.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 433.
Wide character (U+2018) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 371.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 371.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 373.
Wide character (U+2018) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 376.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 376.
Wide character (U+2018) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 380.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 380.
Wide character (U+2018) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 390.
Wide character (U+2018) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 390.
Wide character (U+2018) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 390.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 390.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 390.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 390.
Wide character (U+2018) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 391.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 391.
Wide character (U+2018) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 391.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 391.
Wide character (U+2018) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 395.
Wide character (U+2018) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 395.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 395.
Wide character (U+2018) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 422.
Wide character (U+2018) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 422.
Wide character (U+2019) in substitution (s///) at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm line 422.
```

And, as I say, that *should* work if I just call `set_locale('en_US.UTF-8')`. But it doesn't

Even `no warnings 'locale'` doesn't affect these warnings, and the only way I have found to get this going is to patch the `Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm` file to comment out `use locale` from line 194 (I am looking at version 0.29 of the module, which is the latest at the time of writing.)

With that change, I get this

#### output

```
Paragraphs: [
  "Here's a \x{2018}quoted\x{2019} string. (The quotes are \"wide\" characters.) Another sentence in the same line. And another.\n",
  "\n",
  "Here's another paragraph. With a second sentence.\n",
  "\n",
  "\n",
  "\n",
]

Sentences in paragraph 1: [
  "Here's a \x{2018}quoted\x{2019} string.",
  "(The quotes are \"wide\" characters.)",
  "Another sentence in the same line.",
  "And another.",
]

Sentences in paragraph 2: undef

Sentences in paragraph 3: ["Here's another paragraph.", "With a second sentence."]

Sentences in paragraph 4: undef

Sentences in paragraph 5: undef

Sentences in paragraph 6: undef
```

Note that the `undef` values are correct, and correspond to blank lines in the input

I will raise this with Kim Ryan, the maintainer of this module, and see what she(he?) has to say. In the mean time I hope this helps

Comment: Looks fantastic, thank you - I'll investigate further on Monday.

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of this module. As far as I can see, the problem has nothing to do with the locale setting. The error messages also appears when using set_locale('en_US.UTF-8');

The issue is that you have a few utf8 characters (left quote etc) mixed in with ASCII ones. When the module does a substitution function on your text, it needs to issue a warning that it is dealing with multi byte data. It doesn't effect the result, it still splits the sentences correctly.

If you could convert your input data to be only ASCII then the error would  not be there. This can be done by saying the following (plus any other chars you want to map, besides the curly quotes).

$txtdat  =~ s/[‘’]/'/g;

before calling get_sentences

A work around is to comment out the 'use warnings;' line in Sentence.pm . I feel that it is reasonable to issue theese warnings though, as others may want to be infomred of mixed encodings in their data streams.

Comment: Hi Kim, thank you for taking the time to look at this and reply. I'll investigate which characters are causing the warnings and how they can best be converted.

Comment: Hi Kim, just looking further into this - do you mean that the module doesn't support UTF-8, or that there's a problem with the encoding in these files? I set the input to UTF-8 using binmode.

Comment: Hi Dom, the problem is that basic  perl function such as regexp search and replace and print are desgined to work with single byte characters. If they detect mutli-byte characters, they issues a warning. 

As I mentioned, the sentences are still split correctly. Using binmode and utf prgams won't stop these warnings. Yourtext data is correctly encoded. But if you don't want ot see the warnings, you need  to first replace all the multibyte sequences with their ASCII equivalents.